# Gitlab pipeline docker error: during connect: Get "http://docker:2375/v1.24/info": dial tcp: lookup docker on 172.31.0.2:53: no such host

Tags: docker, gitlab

One week ago the Gitlab pipeline was working fine. The code is shown below. But then it is suddenly failing although nothing has been done in the docker-runner and no config were changes. The error is: `ERROR: error during connect: Get "http://docker:2375/v1.24/info": dial tcp: lookup docker on 172.31.0.2:53: no such host`

```
  image:
    name: python:3.8
    entrypoint: [ "" ]
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  services:
    - docker:19.03.0-dind
  before_script:
    # Install docker
    - apt update --assume-yes
    - apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common --assume-yes
    - curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
    - curl -O https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/buster/pool/stable/amd64/containerd.io_1.4.3-1_amd64.deb
    - apt install ./containerd.io_1.4.3-1_amd64.deb
    - add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"
    - apt update --assume-yes
    - apt-cache policy docker-ce
    - apt install docker-ce --assume-yes
    - docker info
```